# how do I have to invoke project while creating a build job in jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, continuous-integration

This problem is buzzing in my ears from past 1 hour. 
how do I have to invoke a project while creating a build job in jenkins.
By using Freestylebuild I create a build job. I give build name, description, add maven, add subversion path and save it. The main problem is I dont find the link between this build and my project.
To ask much simpler How to create a build job for my java project. While creating build where should I specify my project in the build ??

Pls. Any appropriate answers will be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a job, do you see this section ?

[image]

Just click on `Add build step` and choose cmd/shell/maven - whataver script your project uses for a build.

Comment: Hi. Thank you very much. My project is using POM Script. I want to add Maven. I clicked on Add build step and selected invoke maven high level target. Selected Latest Maven version and saved. Here I just invoke maven but where will I specify my project in build?

Comment: 1. If u r using a version control tool - then look at the section called source code management within the same page above `Build Triggers` , select the versioned path/url where your project parent POM lies. 
2. If you do not use version control, Jenkins will default to building from the current workspace. So it will look for `$WORKSPACE/pom.xml`
3. If you want to change the workspace goto `Manage Jenkins > Configure` - see the top section `Home Directory`, click `Advanced` and change the workspace directory

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `build step`, perhaps `Invoke maven` as you have mentioned that in the question. Fill the appropriate parameters in the configuration fields and then trigger the build.

I am not very familiar with [maven](http://maven.apache.org/), but if you are using [ant](http://ant.apache.org/), you create a new `build step` `Invoke ant` and then specify the ant target. This will build the project specified by the ant scripts.

Comment: If i am not wrong 1) Build step is creating a new build job 2) Invoke maven is specifying maven version and goal while creating build 3) specify the maven or ant target??? .Can you please let me know what do you mean by specify ant target.

Comment: Ant target is specific to ant scripts. I guess you are not using ant, but maven. So you need not bother about that.